# Exercise with minimal prime ideals and zero-divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be a ring, and let $D\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}A$ be the set of the prime ideals $p$ with this property: there is $a\in A$ such that $p$ is minimal in the set of the prime ideals containing $(0:a)$. Show that $x\in A$ is a zero-divisor iff $x\in p$ for some $p\in D$.

If $x$ is a zero-divisor, there is $a\in A$ such that $x\in (0:a)$. The set of the prime ideals containing $(0:a)$ has a minimal element, that is the desired prime ideal.

Now suppose that $x\in p$, where $p$ is a prime ideal, minimal over $(0:a)$. My idea was to localize at $p$: the ideal $(0:a)$ survives in $A_p$, and its radical becomes $pA_p$. This means that (in $A_p$) we have $\left(\frac x1\right)^r=\frac ys$, for $y\in (0:a)$, $s\in A\setminus p$ and $r$ a positive integer. So there is $t\in A\setminus p$ such that $x^rst=yt$ in $A$, yelding $x^rsta=0$.

Is this solution correct? I always get confused when I reason with localized ring

Comment: The solution looks correct.